# How to solve twitterbootstrap sub menu overlapping issue in mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap bootply.

http://www.bootply.com/3ZcMmRL4a0

My problem is when I see this in mobile dropdown is not really showing well.Its going top of other menus.I know there is something in my codes.Can someone point it to me?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you try my answer?? @user1353519

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">welcome</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="Personale">menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu4<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://www.bootply.com/tWPiXKPEWq

Check it in http://www.responsinator.com